# Change nopcommerce default action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

How to change nopcommerce default action?

I create new action in `HomeController`, and want to be default page.

I change:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

To:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "NewAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

But nothing has changed.

Comment: Waht URL are you navigating to /, /Home, /Home/Index ?

Comment: /. and want to run /Home/NewAction method

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to /Home/Index, MVC parses route as follows:

- Controller: Home
- Action: Index
- Id:

If you navigate to /Home:

- Controller: Home
- Action: NewAction (from route's default action)
- Id:

You can make it always activate `NewAction` like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "", 
    "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "NewAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
//your default action
public ActionResult Index()
{
return RedirectToAction("NewAction"); //Like Response.Redirect() in Asp.Net WebForm
}

//your new action
public ActionResult NewAction()
{
//some code here
  return view();
}
```